# Getting a Rails App to Work with Git Pages to Create a Personal Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-pages

I created a git page -> `https://github.com/username/username.github.io.git`

I then created a workspace in Cloud9-IDE and cloned `https://github.com/username/username.github.io.git`

Then I installed Rails from the terminal `gem install rails -v 5.0.1`
and create a new Rails app `rails _5.0.1_ new blog`, I created a `'Hello World'` home page and confirmed that it was working locally with Rails Server.

I then committed the changes and pushed successfully to GitHub, the commits are visible in the repo.

```
git add -A 
git commit -m "message" 
git push
```

However, when visiting `https://username.github.io` I do not see anything other than `username.github.io` from the README at the top of the page.

Comment: You cannot run Rails on xxx.github.io. It supports only html files.

Comment: i can accept as an answer! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Rails is a dynamic system, meaning that the pages are generated from templates combined with data. Github Pages only servers static HTML, so even if you put static content into Rails, you would not be able to run the scripts that serve it.

If you really need Rails, use [Heroku](https://heroku.com) free plan.